# Awaiting promises which is assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Consider the below code,

```
// Function which returns a promise and resolves in 2 seconds
const promiseFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
};

// Asynchronous function 1
const asyncFunction1 = async() => {
    console.log(await promiseFunction());
    console.log(await promiseFunction());
    console.log(await promiseFunction());
}

// Asynchronous function 2
const asyncFunction2 = async() => {
    let a = promiseFunction();
    let b = promiseFunction();
    let c = promiseFunction();

    console.log(await a);
    console.log(await b);
    console.log(await c);
}
```

I am trying to understand the behaviour between asyncFunction1 and asyncFunction2 execution, 
the asyncFunction1 takes 2 seconds for each await (total 6) when not assigned to a variable, but asyncFunction2
resolves all the 3 promises in total 2 seconds when assigned to a variable, what happens here when it is
assigned to a variable? (and we still use await with the variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timers start when you call `promiseFunction()`, thus when you `await a`, all three timers are already running. Then when `a` finishes after 2 seconds, the other ones are already done too.

Comment: Of course, you're right. But I think explaining the basic of promise would be good for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The **callback function** passed in the Promise constructor **is started to execute when the promise is created**(This is the main difference between Observable and Promise). Please take a look at the first code.

```js
// Asynchronous function 1
const asyncFunction1 = async() => {
    console.log(await promiseFunction());
    console.log(await promiseFunction());
    console.log(await promiseFunction());
}
```

This function waits for 2 minutes for each function so it would take 6 seconds. While the second function doesn't work the same way.

```js
// Asynchronous function 2
const asyncFunction2 = async() => {
    let a = promiseFunction();
    let b = promiseFunction();
    let c = promiseFunction();

    console.log(await a);
    console.log(await b);
    console.log(await c);
}
```

It executes the 3 callback functions simultaneously. It works exactly like await Promise.all(). Therefore asyncFunction2 would be resolved in about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For

**asyncFunction1**

1. They will initiate the function one after one.That means second function was wait until first function end.
2. Because you call the function directly on await

**asyncFunction2**

1. For this case it will initiate all the function same time. so that function was trigger on immediate call. so that timer was started immediate
2. That's why all the function  executed at the same time

*Check my below console .you can see the different*

```js
const promiseFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
};

// Asynchronous function 1
const asyncFunction1 = async() => {
    console.log(await promiseFunction(),1);
    console.log(await promiseFunction(),1);
    console.log(await promiseFunction(),1);
}

// Asynchronous function 2
const asyncFunction2 = async() => {
    let a = promiseFunction();
    let b = promiseFunction();
    let c = promiseFunction();

    console.log(await a,2);
    console.log(await b,2);
    console.log(await c,2);
}
asyncFunction1();
asyncFunction2();
```